# which of the following statement is true ?..

Tags: general-topology

Consider with the usual Euclidean metric d. Let $X$ = {$(x,\frac{1}{x})\in R^2 | 
x > 0$} ∪ {$(0, y) ∈R^2$
| y ≥ 0} ∪ {$(x, 0) ∈ R^2
| x ≥ 0$}. Then

which of the following statement  is true ?

a. X is open but not closed.

b. X is neither open nor closed.

c. X is closed but not open.

d. X is open and closed.

I think in subspace  topology   X  will be open set.... so option a)  will corrects

Any hints /solution..Pliz help  me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is c). 'Open' and 'closed' refer to the topology of $\mathbb R^{2}$ not the subspace topology of $X$.

Comment: thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy